# How to remove windows from MacBook pro and install ubuntu?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have MacBook pro mid-2010 it's running  Completely in windows. I want to remove windows completely and replace with ubuntu completely

Answer (score 1):

During Ubuntu's installer you can select option *"Erase disk and install Ubuntu"* to get rid of Windows. **This will remove everything on your laptop so take backups if you need!**